# KeyError: 'years', Python

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

I'm trying plot a df, but i always find that error: KeyError: 'value'

I already tried define the value as .set_index(''), also tried for other columns, tried define xlabel and ylabel before try the plot but i never had a different result from this.

My idea is 'years' be the xlabel, and the ylabel be the values of each other column.

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\Industrial\dados_agregados1.csv', sep = ';', header = 0)

df2 = df.T

df2.head(1)

print(type(df2))

df2.plot(x = 'years')

i had less than 10 reputations, so, i cant post here the image.

Thanks for all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvRJM.jpg)

Comment: check `df.columns` , check `years` there ?

Comment: yep, return exactly what i need

Comment: Try to format your code by using ```. Place them before and after the code snippet, so that it will monospace it and make it look more readable to other users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set your first row as columns

```py
df2 = df.T
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
df2 = df2.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
df2.head(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that can be seen in the image is that you mix (due to transpose) column names with actual values (meaning, the row starting with "Years" is seen as data instead of the header).

Solution would be to do something like (full example select only what you require):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1':["CompanyABC", 1000, 1200] , 'col2': ["CompanyXYZ", 333,222]}, index=["Years", 2002, 2003])

# From here would apply to you
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df_new = df.drop('Years')
df_new.plot.bar()
```

Comment: if i use the transpose i receive another error with expected values was 24, but i only received 15, and i dont i yet receive a Keyerror